# AJAX: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, api

I'm trying to learn AJAX and I am having some problems with the request. Whenever I sent a request I'm able to console.log the data, however, I also get an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is the JSON data which it is requesting.

```
{"data":{"id":"633","name":"test_name","none":"0"}}
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: reqURL,
    timeout: 10000,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log(data, status)
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Error!")
    }
});
```

Help appreciated! :)

Comment: Are You using "length" function anywhere? Check what line in script causes error. Provide full code because there is nothing to fix there.

Comment: so your `ajax` is working, it's some your other code's problem. Provide full code. Please

Comment: None of the code you've shown uses `.length`, so this code is not throwing the error.  Please edit your question to show the problem code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Nginx config (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default). I hadn't configured the query strings properly. I had to change it to.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Hope this helps if people are having this problem!

Answer (score -1):

Try to parse the json data that you're getting in return with JSON.parse(data)

Comment: I think that the dataType property already takes care of the conversion.